# Python - "break" statement breaking outside loops

Tags: python, loops

When the user is done with the game (answers all the questions), the game is supposed to break the game loop and go back to the password prompt, but it instead breaks the entire program loop and the game while loop and ends the program. 
any Ideas?

```
access = 1
score = 0

print("Hello, user.\n")

while i < 5:

    input1 = input("Enter Password:\n")

    if input1 == password:
        print("Access Granted\n\n-----------------------------\n")


        r2 = input("Enter 1: Play 20 Questions\nEnter 2: Change your password\nEnter 3: Decrypt a message\nEnter 4: Encrypt a Message\nEnter 5: Exit Terminal\n\n")

        #20 Questions
        while r2 == "1" and access == 1:


            questions = ["Who was the first president of the United States?", "what is the USA's biggest state?", "What USA city has the most tourism?", "Where are most tech companies located?"
                     , "how many branches of the military are there?", "how many states are in the US", "When was the Decleration of Independence signed?", 
                     "What form of government is the USA?", "", "", ""]
            answers = ["george washington", "alaska", "new york", "silicon valley", "5", "50", "1777", "Constitutional Republic"]


            print(questions[i])
            answer = input("")

            #If answer is correct
            if answer == answers[i]:
                score += 1
                print("Correct! your score is now")
                print(score)
                i += 1

                if i == 7:
                    break
            else:
                print("Wrong, your score is still")
                print(score)
                i += 1

                if i == 7:
                    break

    else:
        print("\nAccess Denied\n")
        i += 1

        if i == 5:
            print("You have run out of attempts.")
            access = 2
        continue
```

Comment: what about using functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer while loop has the condition `while i < 5` but your break statement happens when `i` is `7`... the `break` keyword is breaking out of the inner loop, but since `i` is not `< 5` the outer loop also finishes.

Answer (score 0):

By the time your code hits the break statement, you'll have `i=7`, so when Python goes to re-evaluate the main loop's condition it will be false. It appears that you should instead have this be a simple `while True` loop in order for your break statement to have the intended effect.

Make sure to reset `i` appropriately before you run through the game a second time.